# draw a dual y axis diagram using php

Tags: php

I have a requirement where I have two y axis. Hence I want a bar chart for y-axis on left and a line diagram for y-axis on the right.

[image: Example]

Can you help me locate the correct GPL PHP library for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
tvks

Comment: Have you looked at GD Library? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Firstly, this link specified above does not display images. I am not sure which one actually matches my requirement as image above.
Secondly, as Corbin says it would be good if you can help me with a much decent looking grapsh.

Comment: rgraph.net does exactly seem to match my requirement. But, does not work on IE 8 :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe both [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) (GPL) and [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net) (QPL 1.0 which restricts you to non commercial use) would fit your needs.

Comment: I tried going around both the websites but could not locate a model like mine (1 bar and 1 line graphs). Can you help me locate it ?

Comment: Ah looks like pChart has moved (http://www.pchart.net/).  http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.combo.charts.html should get you going :).

Comment: http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.combo.charts.html does exactly match my requirements excluding the values in the right y axis. I have been having a tough time trying to register in their forum to ask this question.

Comment: Am not very familiar with pChart, so am afraid I won't be able to help you there.  It's likely possible via some method, but I'm not sure on the specifics (probably something legend, scale or axis-label related).

Comment: I downloaded pchart ver 2 and tried the same combo chart and it does not have the specified header class files. This seems to be an example of ver 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try JpGraph: http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto5.php

Comment: You should be aware of the licensing conditions of JpGraph, especially as he mentioned GPL: "JpGraph is released under a dual license. QPL 1.0 (Qt Free License) For non-commercial, open-source or educational use and JpGraph Professional License for commercial use."

Comment: I tried going around the website but could not locate a model like mine (1 bar and 1 line graphs). Can you help me locate it ?

Comment: Combined line and bar plots: http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar6.php

Comment: Thank you Datamosh !! The diagram matches all my requirements except the second y-axis having labels of the line diagram. Pls help me on that..